# Google map javascript api doesnt display when I use height as percentage

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, reactjs

Google map javascript api doesnt display when I use height as percentage but when i use px it display. I need it to be 95% of my browser, how do i do this? I am using react

```
.map {
    width: 65%;
    /*height: 95%;*// doesnt works. why?
    height: 680px; // works?
}
```

map.jsx

```
<div id="mapCanvas">
   <Map name="map"/>
</div>
```

home.jsx

```
render () {
    console.log("Render Map")
    return <div className="map" id="map"></div>
}
```

Comment: can you post complete code to here please, i think this is because the parent node of .map has no height

Comment: @MaYubo Yuboi am using react

Answer (score 0, accepted):

resize the map canvas when the screen height changes

```
componentDidUpdate () {
    $(window).resize(function () {
        const h = $(window).height(),
        offsetTop = 85; // Calculate the top offset
        $('#map').css('height', (h - offsetTop));
    }).resize()
},
```